# How can I search for something in a text file and output it's details in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, menu, text-files

The aim of my program is to display a menu that will be able to provide you with the ability to add a new "Book" with it's details like author, price and copies to a text file. The second part of the program should ask a user for an input of an Author's name which then the program has to look for that Author's name in the text file and display the books, prices and copies related to that Author. My issue is I am not sure exactly how to do the second part.A "line" is divided into 4 parts, Author, book, Price and Copies. Author holds 16 characters, book holds 20 characters, price holds 5 and copies hold 2. Let's say the author is J.K. Rowling, that is 12 characters, I have a function that adds " "(spaces) to satisfy the condition of it being 16. Same goes for all the divisions. By the end of it let's say it's J.K. Rowling    Harry Potter Book 2 12.9912. 
Author: "J.K. Rowling    "
Book: "Harry Potter Book 2 "
Price: "12.99"
Copies: "12"
That's technically the explanation for the first part. The second part should search for "J.K. Rowling" and then get the results of:

Author: "J.K. Rowling    "
Book: "Harry Potter Book 2 "
Price: "12.99"
Copies: "12"

If there is a much more efficient way than this then it would be greatly appreciated but for now part 2 is the main issue.

p.s. It has to be done through the text file

Full Program(part 1 works):

```
def AddSpaces(auth,numb):
    print("Runs")
    while len(auth) < numb:
        auth = auth + " "
    return (auth)



menu = 1
while menu <= 2:
    menu = int(input("1. Add a new book\n2. Search for a new book by a given author\n3. End"))
    if menu ==1:

        BOOKS = open("BOOKS.txt","a")

        Author = str(input("Author: "))
        if len(Author) < 16:
            Author = AddSpaces(Author,16)
        while len(Author) > 16:
            Author = str(input("Author: "))
            Author = AddSpaces(Author,16)
        print(Author)

        Book = str(input("Book: "))
        if len(Book) < 20:
            Book = AddSpaces(Book,20)
        while len(Book) > 16:
            Book = str(input("Book: "))
            Book = AddSpaces(Book,20)
        print(Book)

        Price = str(input("Price: "))
        while len(Price)>5:
            Price = str(input("Price: "))

        Copies = str(input("Copies: "))
        while len(Copies)>2:
            Copies = str(input("Copies: "))

        line = Author + Book + Price + Copies +"\n"
        print(line)
        BOOKS.write(line)
        BOOKS.close()


    elif menu == 2:
        BOOKS = open("BOOKS.txt","r")
        while True:
            AuthorSearch = str(input("Author name for search: "))
            if len(AuthorSearch) < 16:
                AuthorSearch = AddSpaces(AuthorSearch,16)
            while len(AuthorSearch) > 16:
                AuthorSearch = str(input("Author name for search: "))
                AuthorSearch = AddSpaces(AuthorSearch,16)
            print(AuthorSearch)

            n = BOOKS.read()
            if n == "":
                print("End of file, no books found")
                break
            if AuthorSearch == line[:16]:
                print ("Author found.")
                print ("Author name: ") + (line[:16])
                print ("Book name: ") + (line[17:36])
                print ("Price: ") + (line[37:41])
                print ("Copies: ") + (line[42:43])
```

Comment: I think it would have been simpler to choose a delimiter between fields rather than fixed-length fields. Then a simple split would provide a list of the various fields.  The delimiter would be something that wouldn't appear in your text such as tab or other ASCII special characters.  This would remove the need to process based upon field widths all over the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a simple modification of your code that handles part 1 & 2**

Mods based upon the following

1. Use Python variable naming convention [Pep
   8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
2. Use tab delimited line to avoid having to work with fixed field
   widths
3. Use [lower()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower) to provide case insensitive comparison
4. Use string [title()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/title-in-python/)
   to ensure the first letter of each word is capitalized for author
   and book name

**Refactored Code**

```
while True:
  menu = input("1. Add a new book\n2. Search for a new book by a given author\n3. End\n")
  if menu in ('1', '2', '3'):
    menu = int(menu)
  else:
    print('Error -- Menu needs to be 1, 2, or 3')
    continue

  if menu == 1:
      author = input("Author: ")
      book = input("Book: ")
      price = input("Price: ")
      copies = input("Copies: ")

      line = '\t'.join([author.title(), book.title(), price, copies])
      with  open("BOOKS.txt","a") as books:
        print(line)
        books.write(line + "\n")

  elif menu == 2:
      author_search = input("Author name for search: ")
      if not author_search:
        print("Need author's name")
        continue  # quit on blank line for author

      author_search = author_search.lower()
      with open("BOOKS.txt","r") as books:
        found = False
        for line in books:
          # Will print all books by this author
          book_info = line.rstrip().split("\t")

          if author_search == book_info[0].lower(): # use lower to make case insensitive match
            found = True
            print('>>> Found Author')
            author, bookname, price, copies = book_info
            print(f'Author name: {author.title()}') # capitable firs letter of each name
            print(f'Book: {bookname.title()}')
            print(f'Price: {price}')
            print(f'Copies: {copies}')
        if not found:
          print('Author not found')
  else:
    break
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you very much for your time, it works perfectly. I just have a question, where does "bookname" come into play? Why was it changed from book to bookname?

Comment: @AbdullaAlzaabi--I used bookname since thought that was slightly more descriptive.  You can change to book by having: `author, book, price, copies = book_info`.  Then change the print to `print(f'Book: {book.title()}')`.